# How do I serve this video file for download using pyramid FileResponse

Tags: pyramid, kotti

Please what am i missing. I keep on getting internal server error in browser when I want to serve this video file that has been downloaded on disk.
here is my code: The view function

```
@view_config(name='download_video')
def dl(request):
    url = request.params.get('url')
    camefrom = request.params.get('came_from')
    path_dir = request.registry.settings['app.download_path']
    result= save_to_disk(url, path_dir)
    if result:
        filename = result['filename']
        filepath = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(path_dir,filename))
        file_exists = os.path.exists(filepath)
        if file_exists:
            res = FileResponse(filepath,content_type='video/mp4')
            res.headers['Content-Length'] = os.path.getsize(filepath)
            res.headers['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment;filename=%s'%filename
            return res
    request.session.flash(_("Error downloading video, please check your network","danger"))
    return HTTPFound(location=camefrom)
```

The template

```
<a tal:attributes="href api.url(api.root, '@@download_video', query={'came_from': request.url,'url':context.video_url})" class="btn">Download</a>
```

The video downloads and I can see it in the folder but I keep on getting internal server error without tracebacks on browser

My app depends on Kotti cms

Comment: Does the server that this runs on not have an error log? Any errors should be logged there with specific messages

Comment: No error log. I keep seeing internal server error in browser. That "
The server encountered an unexpected internal server error" .

Comment: Your server does not have an error log? What kind of server is it? (I know neither pyramid nor kotti)

Comment: My server has error log but this particular error is not logged

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm m not sure what's going on with your Pyramid logging but here is my view for downloading a file. I'm currently on an iPhone so I just cut and pasted but you should get the idea.

```
@view_config(route_name="download_view", renderer="")
def server_view1010(request):
    filepath = os.path.join(CFG.home_dir, "static/graphics/imgs/img_sample.jpg")
    if request.storage.exists(filepath):                                                     #there is no overwrite
        response = FileResponse(filepath)
        response.headers['Content-Disposition'] = ("attachment; filename=img_sample.jpg")
        return response
    else:
        return Response("Unable to find: {}".format(request.path_info))
```

Comment: This helped me. Was doing an HTTP redirection while I was supposed to return a response. I returned a response and later found out that the issue is from my video extractor. Thanks. Also configured logging for the app. Kotti doesn't come with configured logger

Comment: Glad it helped: )